# I want to start a slideshow on hover on a image in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a main image in the index.html file. Beneath it, three small thumbnail images are present. The main image will change according to the image on which hovered. This is working perfectly fine.
Now, I want to add new functionality in which after the first hover, the image changes automatically after 1 second (for test purpose).

What I tried is calling the setInterval function in updateMainImage method of the component. The index number is changing after each second but not the image. Here are the relevant code snippets.

```
Vue component:
    data(){
    return {
        imagenumber: 0,
        image:'images/ims.jpg',
        slideshowimages: [
            {
                id: 1,
                img: 'images/ims.jpg',
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                img: 'images/ims2.jpg',
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                img: 'images/ims3.jpg',
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

methods

```
updateMainImage(img,index){
        this.image = img
        console.log(index)
        var timer= setInterval(function(){
            if(index<2){
                index++
                console.log(index)
                this.image= slideshowimages[index].img
            }
            else{
                index=0
                console.log(index)
            }
        },1000)
    }
```

template

```
<div class="wrapperThumbnailforMainImage">
        <div class="thumbnailForMainImage" v-for="(image, index) in 
         slideshowimages" :key="image.id">
        <img :src="image.img" 
         @mouseover="updateMainImage(image.img,index)">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want the image of the respective index number to be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the updated code.

```
updateMainImage(img,index){
        this.image = img
        console.log(index)
        var timer= setInterval(function(){
            if(index<2){
                index++
                console.log(index)
                this.image= slideshowimages[index].img
            }
            else{
                index=0
                this.image= slideshowimages[index].img
                console.log(index)
            }
        },1000)
    }
```